# (Admin API) User Abilities Update returning 400

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

We would like to update user abilities, but I can't seem to get this PUT request to work. Does anybody have an example of the message body for the User Abilities Update path?

What I have done so far:

- Verified that my test user has all necessary permissions
- Tested the auth token with other endpoints (GET requests work just fine)
- Reviewed my institution abilities metadata for valid typing

Here's an example of what I'm attempting to send:

```
-------------------- REQUEST --------------------
Method: PUT
URI: https://banno.com/a/mobile/api/v0/institutions/{institution_uuid}/users/{user_uuid}/abilities/update
Headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5...",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
Body: {
    "travel_notices": False,
    "zelle_enabled": "None"
}
-------------------- RESPONSE --------------------
Status: 400 - Malformed json, invalid keys/values, no key/values
```

Any advice would be very much appreciated!

RESOLVED:
I am using the Python [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library to submit these calls, and I was not converting the dict payload to JSON format before sending.

Comment: It could be an issue with the JSON in the body - could you retry it using lowercase on the boolean field, ie. `"travel_notices": false`?

Comment: Ah, nice catch. Thanks! I'm using Flask / Python to submit the requests, and I wrongly assumed the payload was being converted to JSON when it wasn't.